# Crontab schedule not running

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

So I'm trying to make some python script run every 6 hours using crontab but for some reason it doesn't work.

**crontab -l**

```
0 */6 * * * cd /home/david/InstaPy && /usr/bin/python3 quickstart.py
>> david.log
```

Also tried to run it every minute for checking purposes but that doesn't work either. Looked through the crontab log file and also not seeing it executing - `var/log/syslog`

Comment: check your user's rights on the files and on contrab

Comment: User is allowed to use crontab I used `touch /etc/cron.allow` then used `echo "david"  > /etc/cron.allow` to allow the username `david` to run it.

Comment: do the functon get enougth time to execute itself?

Comment: I’m sorry but I didn’t understand you’re question.

Comment: Does /home/david/InstaPy exist?  If not, the script will silently exit.

Comment: @FrankMerrow Yes, for second check I've clicked "Properties" on the python script and it gave me the same path which is `/home/david/InstaPy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Crontab :

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
```

1- first of all I would suggest you execute the process with :

```
0 */6 * * * cd /home/david/InstaPy && python3 /yourpath/quickstart.py
```

2-Ensure the file has execute permissions.

```
chmod +x /path/to/file
```

3-check that your password hasn't expired., since once it has, all cron jobs stop

4- try to redirect the output of your process :

```
0 */6 * * * cd /home/david/InstaPy && /usr/bin/python3 quickstart.py >> /whateverpath/sample.log 2>&1
```

5- check your environment variables :

```
0 */6 * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command/to/run
```

In this case it will pick all the environment variable defined in your `$HOME/.profile file.

Comment: 1. I did try to execute the process with the following `1 * * * * cd /home/david/InstaPy && python3 /home/david/InstaPy/quickstart.py >> /home/david/instapy.log 2>&1
`. When copy pasting this to the terminal the scripts starts without any problems.
2. I gave the file execute premissions with `chmod +x /home/david/InstaPy/quickstart.py`
3. Password hasn't expired.
4. Path right now is `1 * * * * cd /home/david/InstaPy && python3 /home/david/InstaPy/quickstart.py >> /home/david/instapy.log 2>&1`
5. `0: command not found` then it displays Python 3.8.2 >>>` Any thing else I could try to do?

Comment: i think your issue with an environment variable,there's difference between interactive-shells and login-shells-non-login-shell.